# linux curl save as utf-8

Tags: linux, curl

Trying to use linux curl to download an xml file from an url.

Pretty sure that the xml is encoded in UTF-8,

suspecting curl -o doesnt save as UTF-8.

Is there anyway to force save to UTF-8 with curl ?

---

Thanks for the suggestion, what i found out:

Because the xml feed is dynamic, not all the time it contain any utf-8 characters. 
Sometimes it doesnt have utf-8 character in the whole content at all even though it is set as utf-8 in the xml encoding and header content type: charset=utf-8. When it contain a utf-8 character at least, it will be save as utf-8.

When this happen, curl doesn't download as utf-8, which makes sense as there are no utf-8 chars, why is there a need to store as utf-8.

This is damn tricky, some validator has to valid against utf-8 hence i still need a solution to force it to utf8 because by default all my xml shld be in utf8-encoding.

tried the suggested by using iconv f iso8859-1 utf-8 doesnt work for this case as i am suspecting it is not in iso8859-1 either.

Still need a better solution.

Comment: I don't believe `curl` makes any modifications at all to what it fetches, and it certainly doesn't re-encode text.

Comment: hi thanks... however i'm not looking re-encode data, just wondering why it is not saving as utf-8 while the contents are alr utf-8

Comment: What makes you think it's not saving as utf-8? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 17):

curl does not do any conversion of the file it downloads. If the HTTP server serves you the XML in another encoding (e.g., ISO8859-1) that his how curl will save it to disk too.

To workaround your problem, you can use "iconv" as follows:

```
curl URL | iconv -f iso8859-1 -t utf-8 > output.xml
```

Hope this help.

Comment: i've tried this way, but it is still downloaded not downloaded as utf-8. i'm pretty sure the xml contents are in utf-8 as i've developed it and checked with mb_check_encoding it returns true with utf-8. How can i check the file encoding standard in linux? i'm not quite sure if it turns out to be iso8859-1 that's why iconv  doesnt work? file -bi doesnt work for me..

Comment: You can check the encoding of a file by typing `file FILENAME`. Please post the output of `file` (against the XML downloaded with curl, without iconv) here.

Comment: If you're on a mac, don't want to rely on iconv, and don't want to hardcode assumptions about the incoming text encoding, you can get the same effect with `curl URL | textutil -cat txt -stdin -stdout -encoding utf-8`

Comment: @algal your method fixed utf8 issue for downloading html, but problem is it returns text only w/o html. Not sure about xml files.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried adding the Accept-Charset header? I had a similar issue downloading a file which was downloading with the wrong encoding.  When I set the Accept-Charset header it works:

```
curl -H "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7" URL | iconv -f iso8859-1 -t utf-8 > output.xml
```