# Flask is not encoding form correctly from cul

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl, flask, character-encoding

I have a simple flask application with one endpoint

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
  if request.method == 'GET':
    return render_template('form.html')
  return request.form['a']
```

the `form.html` looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="a" value="öäü"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

when I open the form in firefox i can enter values like `äöü` send the POST-request end receive the correct response `äöü`.

However, when I simply try to send the POST-request using curl like this:

```
curl http://localhost -F "a=öäü"
```

I get the cryptic response:

```
´┐¢´┐¢´┐¢
```

I also tried the solution from [How do I POST form data with UTF-8 encoding by using curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489530/how-do-i-post-form-data-with-utf-8-encoding-by-using-curl)

```
curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" --data-ascii "a=äöü" http://localhost
```

but i still get the same result. I am using curl on a Windows 7 with codepage `850`

Any help how to even debug this behavior is deeply appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can urlencode the data:

```
curl http://localhost -F "a%3D%C3%B6%C3%A4%C3%BC"
```

To do it automatically `curl` has the `--data-urlencode` flag.

Comment: `--data-urlencode` gives the same output as `-F`. `curl http://localhost -F "a%3D%C3%B6%C3%A4%C3%BC"` gives the output `Warning: Illegally formatted input field!` `curl: option -F: is badly used here`

Comment: Based on your solution I tried it this way: `curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" --data-raw "a=%C3%B6%C3%A4%C3%BC" http://localhost` which works fine. However i am still stuggeling how to generate the string `%C3%B6%C3%A4%C3%BC` from `äöü`

Answer (score 0):

I not windows pc, it's not confirm, you can try `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" --data-urlencode "a=öäü" http://localhost`